# Elasticsearch Aggregations with Date Time range match - Partial Match use case

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working on Elastic Search for use case where I need to do equivalent to following SQL Query:
Basically calculating difference in minutes for flight that has matched partially for first and Last matching record.

ORACLE Query will do it like this:

WITH CTE AS
(SELECT MIN(SCHED_LCL_DEP_DTM) AS MIN_LCL  FROM FA_PAIR_DUTY_FLT_LEG WHERE DEST_ARPT_CD='ORD' AND SCHED_LCL_DEP_DTM BETWEEN '04-MAY-19 18.20.00' AND '08-MAY-19 18.20.00')
SELECT (24*60*(MIN_LCL - to_date('2019-05-04 18.20.00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') )),MIN_LCL FROM CTE;

Couchbase N1QL Query will do it like this:

select DATE_DIFF_STR(test.minVal, '2019-05-16T09:25:00', 'minute') as add_3_days , test.minVal from  (select  min(LayoverStartDtm) as minVal  from CRF_DATA use index(gco_layover_pairingDutyFlightLeg_idx_1)  where docType = 'PairingDutyFlightLeg' and DestAirportCd = 'ORD' and IsLayover = 'Y' and (LayoverStartDtm BETWEEN '2019-05-16T09:25:00' AND '2019-05-16T13:45:00') limit 10) test

Refer to below sample Document. So If my Date range in Query is

(from - '2019-06-05T02:30:00' To '2019-06-05T19:00:00')
then

If I do sum(fdpVal)  then I get 60 + 60 = 120 but this is not what I want.

I want to get exact time slice I want to subtract which is not part of matching range -

(2019-06-05T02:30:00 - 2019-06-05T02:00:00) which is 30 min. that 
So finally I want to do aggregation 30 + 60 (fdpVal) which is 90 is correct value for me.
OR in another words 120 - 30 = 90.

{

"GMTStart": "2019-06-05T02:00:00",

"GMTEnd": "2019-06-05T03:00:00",

"fdpVal":60,

"fileNo": "U127092",

"pairingId":"21938432"

}

{

"GMTStart": "2019-06-05T03:01:00",

"GMTEnd": "2019-06-05T04:00:00",

"fdpVal":60,

"fileNo": "U127092",

"pairingId":"21938432"

}

Could you please help me how to implement this in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

The sample question is kinda messy, please reformat it for ease of reading

I'll give you a sample code snippet, hope you can get an idea

```
$from_date = "2019-06-05T02:00:00";
$to_date = "2019-06-05T03:00:00";

'aggs' => [
    //The "DATE_RANGE" string below is just an identifier of the Elasticsearch Aggs portion for your specific range requirement
    'DATE_RANGE' => [
        "range" => [
            "field" => "my_field",
            "ranges" => [
                [ "from" => $from_date,
                 "to"   => $to_date ],
            ],
            //the "format" below is required if you are specific with your dates' format
            'format' => "yy-MMM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",
        ],
    ]
]
```

Feel free to comment if you have any more questions

Comment: Hello, Thanks for reply. I have rephrased Question. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research and tries I found solution how to do it. Basically we need to use scripting (Painless etc) to achieve it post subset data is available through basic filter query.

Reach out to me in case you need any more details.